# Is "How long can I trust the purity of water in a water bottle?" on topic for The Great Outdoors

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about storing water when on a camping trip or on a multi-day hike.  I'm hoping you can help me to determine whether or not this question is on topic for the site:

### How long can I trust the purity of water in a water bottle?

In the morning on day 1 of my multi-day hike I opened up a one liter plastic bottle of water and drank half the contents.  I stored the bottle in a loop on the outside of my pack and promptly forgot about it.  On day 3, sweating and thirsty I remembered the water bottle, but I worried that I might get an upset stomach if I drank the water.

Was I right to be worried?  How long can I trust the purity of water in a water bottle after it has been opened and exposed to a person's mouth?

---

I'm hopeful that this question is on topic for the site.  I've searched online for an answer to this question, and I've searched the stack, but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere.  What are your thoughts?  Would this question be a good fit for The Great Outdoors?

Comment: Yes, it would be a good fit.  As for the germs because you drank from it, they are your germs.  If you are worried, you can wipe the mouth of the bottle.

Comment: It might be a better fit on health.   I have bottle next to my bed I have used for weeks.    I